# How to use repeat and minmax in tailwind

Tags: reactjs, tailwind-css

Hello I have a question how can I use repeat and minmax in grid in tailwind. I did something like this and it did not work.

```
const DetailedAssetCard = () => {
  return (
    <div className=" bg-gray-100 rounded-lg grid  grid-cols-[repeat(4, minmax(100px, 500px))]  ">
      <div className="w-32 h-32 rounded-full ">
        <Image src={Btc} alt="" />
      </div>

      <p>
        Hello <span className="block ">123</span>
      </p>
      <p>
        Hello <span className="block ">123</span>
      </p>
      <p>
        Hello <span className="block ">123</span>
      </p>
      <p>
        Hello <span className="block ">123</span>
      </p>
      <p>
        Hello <span className="block ">123</span>
      </p>
      <p>
        Hello <span className="block ">123</span>
      </p>
    </div>
  );
};
```

Answer (score 20):

Remove any spaces inside

```
grid-cols-[repeat(4,minmax(100px,500px))]
```

```
const DetailedAssetCard = () => {
  return (
    <div className=" bg-gray-100 rounded-lg grid  grid-cols-[repeat(4,minmax(100px,500px))]  ">
      <div className="w-32 h-32 rounded-full ">
        <Image src={Btc} alt="" />
      </div>

      <p>
        Hello <span className="block ">123</span>
      </p>
      <p>
        Hello <span className="block ">123</span>
      </p>
      <p>
        Hello <span className="block ">123</span>
      </p>
      <p>
        Hello <span className="block ">123</span>
      </p>
      <p>
        Hello <span className="block ">123</span>
      </p>
      <p>
        Hello <span className="block ">123</span>
      </p>
    </div>
  );
};
```

Answer (score 11):

By default, Tailwind includes `grid-template-column` utilities for creating basic grids with up to `12 equal` width columns. You can customize these values by editing `theme.gridTemplateColumns` or `theme.extend.gridTemplateColumns` in your `tailwind.config.js` file.

So your tailwind config file should look like this

```
module.exports = {
  theme: {
    extend: {
     gridTemplateColumns: {
        // added new 4 column grid as new4
        'new4': 'repeat(4, minmax(100px, 500px))'
        }
    },
  },
  plugins: [],
}
```

And use like this `grid-cols-new4`.

```
const DetailedAssetCard = () => {
  return (
    <div className=" bg-gray-100 rounded-lg grid  grid-cols-new4  ">
      <div className="w-32 h-32 rounded-full ">
        <Image src={Btc} alt="" />
      </div>

      <p>
        Hello <span className="block ">123</span>
      </p>
      .
      .
      .
      <p>
        Hello <span className="block ">123</span>
      </p>
    </div>
  );
};
```

A nice example I have created [here](https://play.tailwindcss.com/uhxj8mrUHw?layout=horizontal) to understand more .